# How to upload the data to DataTables plug-in from /dev/console

Tags: jquery, c++, c, ajax, embedded-linux

It seems that I need your expert opinion.

I have embedded system with installed Linux. I would like to use this system to show web page with dynamically content in DataTables plug-in (http://datatables.net/). The date which I would like to show in DataTables will be received on console port (by sending request for data to console and as result the data will be received to this port). 
As I am using embedded system I cannot include peyton/perl and etc Interpreters in my system due to the root fs is too small.

Suggestion solution is to use daemon written on C. It will be every second sending request for data to console port, receiving the data, parse it and updating file with JSON data. This data will be used as AJAX source for DataTables plug-in on my web page.

But I think it is not gracefully way. Maybe is there some existing solutions, how to dynamically get the data from console port and upload it to DataTables plug-in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I take it that some other machine is connected to the embedded system. In which case the easiest is probably to simply send the raw data to the console using a simple program (`cat` if it's available!), and then convert it to `DataTables` format on the machine that collects the data.

Comment: I have microcontroller connected to embedded system via rs232. The embedded system sending requests to microcontroller via console port, and receiving data from that port. Received data is not parsed, a daemon written on C should convert this data to JSON format and put it to source file which will be used for DataTables. It is my way how to solve it. But maybe, is there some gracefully way? Or this way is OK?

Comment: I would suggest that the translation to JSON is done on the receiving side of the RS232. That reduces the programming load, and it also allows the translation program to be written in, for example, Python, since it no longer lives on the embedded system and doesn't have to deal with the low storage concerns.